# Performance of Blocking Collection in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

Blocking Collections are getting more pile up than Normal Queue. In Following Scenario,

1. I have a dedicated Thread as a Consumer.
2. Three or more dedicated Threads as Producer.

   I have checked with Normal Queue (Monitor.Enter...) as well as Blocking Collection.

Results:

```
Both Queues are getting pile up (Obviously , Consumers < Producers)
```

**Normal Queues are automatically cleared at some point & not keep on increasing after 20000 or 30000.
But Blocking Collection are  keep on increasing more than hundreds of thousands and Obviously we have no clear option, at the same time i dont want to restrict the producer**

Can any one Shed some light ..

Comment: You should post code if you can. Also are you using "lakhs" to mean "hundreds of thousands"? I don't think most English speakers are familiar with that term.

Comment: I thought that Lakhs was some obscure reference to bagels and salmon.

Comment: In most work-queue scenarios, the "do the work" is much more important than the dequeue time - if the "do the work" was that trivial it wouldn't have been *queued* - it would have been *done*. Are you sure the issue here isn't simply that the "do the work" is taking longer than it takes to pile up additional work? That isn't the fault of the queue...

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion I keep making - try [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org) out. The producer/consumers pattern is well supported (use PUSH and PULL sockets), and it will be blindingly fast. Since you're using the same process, you have no message loss to worry about.

Comment: I have worked specifically with ZeroMQ for quite a while. I had very high throughput and low latency requirements in needing to stream millions of messages per second. I honestly love ZeroMQ for anything inter-process but cannot recommend it for inproc work simply because it cannot hold up to a custom solution involving concurrent collections and point-to-point message passing. I ended up implementing ZeroMQ for interproc and a customized solution for inproc, connecting the two through a "forwarder" device which I wrote myself.